# Could not find activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (existing is for Java)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongrel, activerecord-jdbc

I've been struggling with this problem for a few hours and it is preventing me from even starting my server, which therefore is stopping development completely.

I am running Windows, Bitnami Rubystack, and that's pretty much it. I downloaded and installed NetBeans yesterday but my primary editor is Notepad++. I am not using JRuby.

Here is the exact message (upon trying to start ruby script/server):

```
irb: gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter' (>= 0), here is why:
  Found activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (0.9.7), but was for platform java
```

I have tried the following commands:

```
gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
gem install activerecord-jdbc-mysql-adapter
gem install --platform java activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (installed but didn't help, uninstalled again)
gem install rails (now 2.3.8)
gem update --system (now 1.3.7)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans tends to modify your config/database.yml to activate jdbc. Since you're not using JRuby you don't need it, you can edit config/database.yml and change jdbc to whatever suits you.